# Count consecutive events

Tags: r, xts

I have daily data for 1 year having 0 and 1 values. I want to calculate monthly events, there is consecutive 1 value for 3 on more days using R?

```
set.seed(123)
abts1 <- sample(0:1, 366, replace=TRUE)

library(xts)
d16 <- seq(as.Date("2016-01-01"), as.Date("2016-12-31"), 1)
ax16 <- as.Date(d16,"%y-%m-%d")
abts12 <- xts(abts1, ax16)
# but it gives events for complete period, not as monthly.
apply.monthly(abts12, function(x) sum(with(rle(c(x!=0)), lengths*values)>=3))
```

Answer (score 0):

The last line of your code throws an error for me when I use xts_0.9-7.

```
R> apply.monthly(abts12, function(x) sum(with(rle(x!=0), lengths*values)>=3))
Error in rle(x != 0) : 'x' must be a vector of an atomic type
```

That's easy to fix though. You just need to wrap `x != 0` in `as.logical`.

```
R> apply.monthly(abts12, function(x) sum(with(rle(as.logical(x!=0)), lengths*values)>=3))
           [,1]
2016-01-31    2
2016-02-29    1
2016-03-31    3
2016-04-30    2
2016-05-31    1
2016-06-30    2
2016-07-31    3
2016-08-31    3
2016-09-30    2
2016-10-31    3
2016-11-30    0
2016-12-31    2
```

That seems like the output you expect. The number of times there are 3 or more consecutive days with a value of 1.